# How to automatically reject incoming calls when the app is terminated using CallKit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I want to send a call rejection notification through CallKit when the app is closed. The following code works properly when executed by a button, but when placed in the applicationWillTerminate method, it executes successfully but cannot reject the call. I would like to know what could be the reason for this.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self endCall];
}
```

```
- (void)endCall {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.callController = [[CXCallController alloc] init];
        if (self.callController.callObserver.calls.count > 0) {
            CXCall *call = self.callController.callObserver.calls.lastObject;
            if (call.hasConnected == NO) {
                // 拒绝通话
                CXEndCallAction *endAction = [[CXEndCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:[[SIMProviderManager sharedInstance] currentCallUUID]];
                CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] initWithAction:endAction];
                [self.callController requestTransaction:transaction completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"End call request transaction failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"End call request transaction success");
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is rarely called. Even when it is called, the app will be terminated long before the code in the `dispatch_after` blocks is ever called. Try without the use of `dispatch_after`.

Comment: @HangarRash "I have tried it, but it still won't reject the call